# Can split the single string by explode?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I looked up splitting the `string` into array in google.I have found that `str_split` is working.By `explode` it's doesn't work in below condition.How can I split the string by explode()?

```
<?php
$string = "EEEE";
print_r(str_split($string));//Array ( [0] => E [1] => E [2] => E [3] => E ) 
print_r(explode("",$string));//Empty delimiter error
?>
```

Comment: When `str_split` is doing the purpose, why `explode`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I heard that str_split will be depreciated,using explode will be more standard from my someone friend !! But actually , I want to know is why doesn't work by explode !! @Sougata

Comment: `explode` needs a delimiter, else error. And `str_split` will be there in **PHP 7** also. So I guess there won't be any problem with `str_split`.

Comment: don't listen only. you can check to the libraries that which function is exist or which function is deprecated. http://php.net/manual/en/index.php

Answer (score -2):

As indicated by your error, explode requires a delimiter to split the string!

You should try,

```
$str = "EEEE";
$answer = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

alternative way would be [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Comment: @downvoter :- What's wrong with my answer ? please comment it off!

Comment: *I have found that str_split is working* - mentioned by OP. Op wants `explode` to do the same.

Comment: Obvious thing is Empty delimiter error! you need delimiter!

Comment: **If delimiter is an empty string (""), explode() will return FALSE** - http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php. Also - *when an empty delimiter is passed to explode, the function not only will return false but will also emit a warning.* - examples.

Comment: @Sougata that was also said by me! As indicated by your error, explode requires a delimiter to split the string!

Comment: first of all I didn't down-voted. but the thing that you mentioned are already mentioned in comment and tried too by OP , may be that is the reason for down-voting.

Comment: @Anant:- Yes agreed! I've shown another way of doing it using preg_split Please review updated answer.

Comment: yes i checked it. so i up-voted you. but yes if anyone down-voting please give reason. I also face this lot of time.I didn't hate down-voting, but at-least reason required so that i can improve my self.

Comment: @downvoter can you please comment ?? Don't do down vote if you don't have reason behind it ! Thanks :)

Comment: @downvoter Go through the above comments as well as answer edits before downvote anywhere! thanks :)